# Create Unitest out of SSH Session / Router CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, paramiko

In my test, a function on a router/switch to be executed via CLI. The function I speak via CLI as a query, and the function does exactly what it should.

Problem now, the unit test, how do I build this?

Output should be:

a.) Connect to SSH

- Works / does not work

b.) prompt opens

- Works / does not work

c.) Command (AAA Accounting) is executed

- Works / does not work

d.) command accounting disable is listed

- Works / does not work

e.) Now, of course, the test should make an output accordingly.

I had looked at some examples but just can not get on.

I used Python 3.7 with the packages Paramiko

I am happy to answer any questions and would be very happy if one or the other could answer accordingly.

This is the function (a part !) I have implemented so far. This also works:

```
s = SSH(host='172.xxx.xxx.xxx', username='xxxx', password='xxxx')
s.query_interactive = True


if s.login():
    q = s.query('aaa') #CLI function open

    #accounting disable function

    q = s.query('accounting disable')

    # show information

    q = s.query('show config')
    print('sysinfo:', q)
```

Comment: what is the function under test? `def do_something(): return something_else`

Comment: Hi, 
the function is:
q = s.query('accounting disable') special 'account disable' on a Switch / Router.

Comment: what does the function return?

Comment: Hi, return is a Show config and a disable / enable in the router config

Comment: sorry this I cannot understand - you are either returning an exit code from the fucntion call and checking it, or you you are able to check the state of the object and fucntion aplied. Under your description it is hard to tell what you can implement.

Comment: Basically, I would like to have the following issue:

I open an SSH session on a router or switch. The output in the test should read:

SSH connection was established (sucessfull) or was not established (negative - test was not passed)

As long as I'm prompt on the router or switch, the next step should be to query router specific commands.

Comment: In my example # $ AAA to change to another Ebende. Again, I need an edition. It tells me positively or negatively.

Now if I execute the command "Account Disable" via a query I would like to see at the end of the output that this test passed, in which I see if the command was executed on the router, if not then I would like a negative result of the test get displayed ..